# Formatting A Textbox's Expression to Currency Format in ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, business-intelligence

I'm doing a report where I need to convert a certain expression into dollar currency. How to convert it into dollar currency PROGRAMMATICALLY, not on formatting it by using the Placeholder Properties Dialog Box and Changing it on the Number section.

Say for example I'm concatenating the text "Total" the the amount.

E.g.

```
Total $140.00
```

When I did the expression:

```
= "Total " & Fields!Amt.Value
```

It turns out something like this:

```
Total 140
```

I want to include the text `"Total"` and format it into dollar currency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```
="Total " & Format(Fields!Amt.Value, "C")
```

Comment: Can i ask you again? I'm using matrix in my reportviewer, how can I make it automatically expanded after the page loaded?